# Get all schedule distinctively and store in array

Tags: cypress

I tried getting this time without repeating and store it in an array to automate if the time is available it will do something else it will go to the next item and check if time is available.

I still have no luck to make this work, any thoughts on how to do this?[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add an example of code that you tried that did not work, as well as the HTML for the webpage.

Comment: Hi @agoff, I updated the question with HTML and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe convert the result `.children()` command to an array with [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
cy.get('div[class^="styles_availability__dataGroup"]') // dropping the hash part of class
  .eq(1)
  .children()
  .then($els => {
    return Array.from($els)
  })
  .should(...
```

Or if you need the text inside each child, add a function as second parameter.

```js
cy.get('div[class^="styles_availability__dataGroup"]')  
  .eq(1)
  .children()
  .then($els => {
    return Array.from($els, el => el.innerText)
  })
  .should(...
```

Can also use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) with [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
cy.get('div[class^="styles_availability__dataGroup"]')  
  .eq(1)
  .children()
  .then($els => {
    return [...$els].map(el => el.innerText)
  })
  .should(...
```

---

#### Looking for availability

Really, this is not best practice, but if you want to find the first `dataGroup` that has some `timeAvailable` as opposed to `timeNotAvailable`, try this

```js
cy.get('div[class^="styles_availability__dataGroup"]')  
  .filter(':has(span:[class^="styles_timeAvailable"])')
  .first()
  .children()
  .then($timeAvailable => {
    ...
  })
```

Comment: Hi @Aladin Spaz, why looking for availability is not the best practice?

Comment: Actually, maybe it's ok - the general idea is you would set up the data for the test so that you ***know*** exactly where the first group with available dates is - say it's the second group - then you don't need code in the test that has to hunt for available dates, the test can focus on asserting whatever you are testing. It's a very general idea based on Arrange/Act/Assert pattern.

Comment: I tried assign a variable to Array.from

var time
cy.get('div[class^="styles_availability__dataGroup"]')  
  .eq(1)
  .children()
  .then($els => {
    time = Array.from($els, el => el.innerText)
  }).then(()=>{
cy.log(time)})

it only returns one value, is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I tested your code with 3 children which have text 'a', 'b', 'c' and I got `log [a, b, c]` in the Cypress log, so it's one array but with 3 values.

Comment: If you get different log, maybe the data is still loading? Hard to guess what the problem is - perhaps you can append results in the question.

Comment: If you think it's due to loading delays, add `.should('have.length.gt', 1)` after `.children()` and before `.then($els => ...`